# How to get missing app into firebase_options?

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a Flutter ios app with two targets, the standard Runner target and an additional `ImageNotification` target which I need for Firebase messaging per [this](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/apple-integration#step-1---add-a-notification-service-extension).

In Firebase I have two apps for ios, one with bundle id
`com.mydom.myapp` and one with `com.mydom.myapp.ImageNotification`

Firebase messaging is working fine in my app but now when i try to use firebase auth I cannot get it to work and then I notice that my `firebase_options.dart` only contains an ios entry for `com.mydom.myapp.ImageNotification`, nothing for `com.mydom.myapp`.

When I run `flutterfire configure` it just detects `Firebase ios app com.mydom.myapp.ImageNotification`, not the main, runner one. Why is this and how do I get Firebase to detect my real app instead of the image notification?

I have tried to delete the ios ImageNotification app from Firebase and reconfigure, in which case it just adds the app back. I have not tried to delete my main app (`com.mydom.myapp`) yet since I have it registered in app store and isn't sure how much work it will lead to if I delete it...

Answer (score 0):

If you have added the app to the Firebase project after `flutterfire configure` you have to re-run it and the `firebase_options.dart` will update.

Comment: yes, indeed that is what should happen. However it is not happening in the case I had with ImageNotification. I had to start over from scratch to overcome this isuue (and then install firebase auth before I started to play with firebase messaging)